# Dividing up a long list of numbers and figuring out the minimum summation of each chunk

Tags: c#

I have been working on three small programs that extract all the sub-strings of a given string (or even a list of integers) as well as all the different combinations of their elements. I now understand them...

My aim to start like this (originally) was to see if I can solve a puzzle, by learning these programs. Here is the puzzle:

Say I am trekking and I have `6` walking distances `{ 11, 16, 5, 5, 12, 10 }` that I would like to finish within `3` days. So, I can do 11 and 16 kilometers during day 1, 5 and 5 kilometers during day 2, and finally 12 and 10 kilometers during day 3.

Perhaps I could do only 11 kilometers during day 1, 16 and 5 and 5 kilometers during day 2, and 12 and 10 kilometers during day 3.

etc . . . etc . . .

My goal is to work out the "minimum" walked distance over the course of these three days. So, in this example, 11 in day 1 and 26 in day 2 and 22 in day 3 would give a maximum of 26, and that 26 is actually the minimum - it does not get better than this.

No matter what combination of three chunks (days) I choose, the daily walked distance doe not get less than 26. For example, if I choose 11+16 for day 1 and 5+5 for day 2 and 12+10 for days 3, I am looking at a max of 27.

However, I cannot quite figure out how to divide up the list elements in 3, which is the number of days. If it was four, I could have four chunks with arbitrary number of distances in each day. And then add up all the divided elements and see which maximum comes out as minimum.

I appreciate this might be a too-big-a-bite for me at this point (I can just about understand the programs that I have put below) but I was wondering if someone perhaps could help me understand this and help me write a function that can handle any number of days and walking stages.

All I have been able to produce so far is a function that can print all the sub-lists and combinations of these 6 walking stages...

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string str = Console.ReadLine();

        for (int i = 1; i <= str.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= (str.Length - i); j++)
            {
                string subStr = str.Substring(j, i);
                Console.WriteLine(subStr);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }



    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> list = new List<int>() { 11, 16, 5, 5, 12, 10 };

        for (int i = 0; i <= list.Count-1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= list.Count-i; j++)
            {
                string subList = string.Concat( list.GetRange(i, j) );
                Console.WriteLine(subList);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }



    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GetCombination( new List<int> { 11, 16, 5, 5, 12, 10 } );

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static void GetCombination( List<int> list )
    {
        double count = Math.Pow(2, list.Count);

        for (int i = 1; i <= (count-1); i++)
        {
            string str = Convert.ToString(i, 2).PadLeft(list.Count, '0');

            for (int j = 0; j < str.Length; j++)
            {
                if ( str[j] == '1' )
                {
                    Console.Write( list[j] );
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the goal of your program? I am still confused after reading your description a few times. Input: Array of Integers (distances of treks), # of sets desired (days) and amount of #'s desired in each set (# of treks in each day), Output : Minimized sum of # in each set (sum of distances) ?

Comment: @Cody G. The input is the number of days, the number of walking stages, and the actual walking stages (distances). The goal is to figure out how much (how many stages) to walk every day, so that at the end, you will have walked the minimum possible distance every day. My first example produces a 26 kilometers, whereas my second example produces a 27, so the first combination of walking distances everyday would be the optimal.

Comment: is it expected that # of days * # of walking stages = # of distances provided? (i.e. that in your example 3 days * 2 treks = I must get 6 distances) --- and that no distance can be used more than once (assumed from your example)

Comment: Why not just sort the walking stages list, then split it into two arrays, one with the first half and one with the second half. Then just add them from opposite ends `List<int> newList = new List<int>(); for(int i = 0, j = array2.Length - 1; i < array1.Length; i++, j--) {newList.Add(array1[i] + array2[j]);}` Would that not get you what you're looking for?

Comment: @ Cody G. No, number of days and number of walking stages are nothing to do with each other. I could have 3 days and 20 little stages that I should decide how many to do each day, so that the sum of all walking I do each day (day 1 and day 2 and day 3) at the end has a maximum that can not be beaten.

Comment: @Meloviz I should not sort them, because they are the input in that order. So here, I have the choices of 6 consecutive distances, and I should decide how many stages to do each day. In my example, it would be, for example, the first two in the first day, then the second two, and then the last two, which would give a maximum of 27, which cannot be the program's correct output, because the other combination gives a maximum of 26 which is a better max.

Comment: I'm confused on what all the limitations are for this problem. If it can only go in the order 11, 16, 5, 5, 12, 10, then what's the point of this? If you can split up the walking distances, and/or rearrange them, then what are the stipulations for how they can be split up?

Comment: @Meloviz You can consider it like an actual mountain trip where you have 6 accommodations or stops along the way with the given distances, so you wanna adjust your daily walking distance; hence only being able to go in that direction.

Comment: Ok, so you're looking for the lowest maximum of all the possible consecutive combinations of those walking distances spread over three days?

Comment: @Meloviz Exactly. Of course with the possibility of changing the number of days and stages...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem can be solved by [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming). Here is my code for it with top-down approach:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] array = { 11, 16, 5, 5, 12, 10 };
        // change last parameter to the number or days
        int min = MinDistance(array, 0, 0, 3); 
        Console.WriteLine(min);
    }

    static int MinDistance(int[] array, int day, int prevDayDistance, int daysLeft)
    {
        if (day == array.Length)
        {
            return prevDayDistance;
        }
        if (daysLeft == 0)
        {
            return int.MaxValue;
        }

        // Keep walking.
        int keepWalkResult = MinDistance(array, day + 1, prevDayDistance + array[day], daysLeft);

        // Postpone it to the next day.
        int sleepResult = MinDistance(array, day, 0, daysLeft - 1);

        // Choose the best solution.
        return Math.Min(keepWalkResult, Math.Max(prevDayDistance, sleepResult));
    }
}
```

For big input arrays you can consider caching `MinDistance` results for triples  `(day,prevDayDistance,daysLeft)`.

Comment: This is **GENIUS**!  Thank you so much.  It is slightly over my head at the moment, but I wonder if you would know of a great place to start learning dynamic programming quickly?  Cheers

Comment: Sure: https://www.hackerrank.com/domains/algorithms/dynamic-programming

Comment: Hi again, I am still struggling to fully understand this, so I was wondering if you could please explain it a bit more, as well as a few tiny stuff such as why `return int.MaxValue`?

Comment: `return int.MaxValue` is for penalting too much sleeping :-) That is, if you sleep for the last night in the middle of the trek, it's incorrent solution. The other way to write it is to check if we have just 1 day left and just return the sum of days left in the array.